# why the pkgutil.walk_packages() give me wrong modules if the subpackage has same name as some system package/module

Tags: python-3.x

I have package structure like this:

```
example/
├── A
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── x.py
├── a.py
├── b.py
├── __init__.py
└── test
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── test1.py
    └── test.py
```

**All files are empty.**

Directly use iter_modules, it works:

```
>>> for i in pkgutil.iter_modules(path=['./example', './example/test', './example/A']):
    print(i)

    
ModuleInfo(module_finder=FileFinder('./example'), name='A', ispkg=True)
ModuleInfo(module_finder=FileFinder('./example'), name='a', ispkg=False)
ModuleInfo(module_finder=FileFinder('./example'), name='b', ispkg=False)
ModuleInfo(module_finder=FileFinder('./example'), name='test', ispkg=True)
ModuleInfo(module_finder=FileFinder('./example/test'), name='test1', ispkg=False)
ModuleInfo(module_finder=FileFinder('./example/A'), name='x', ispkg=False)
```

But walk_packages give modules in `/usr/lib/python3.8/test`

```
>>> for i in pkgutil.walk_packages(path=['./example',]):
    print(i)

    
ModuleInfo(module_finder=FileFinder('./example'), name='A', ispkg=True)
ModuleInfo(module_finder=FileFinder('./example'), name='a', ispkg=False)
ModuleInfo(module_finder=FileFinder('./example'), name='b', ispkg=False)
ModuleInfo(module_finder=FileFinder('./example'), name='test', ispkg=True)
ModuleInfo(module_finder=FileFinder('/usr/lib/python3.8/test'), name='test.__main__', ispkg=False)
ModuleInfo(module_finder=FileFinder('/usr/lib/python3.8/test'), name='test.ann_module', ispkg=False)
ModuleInfo(module_finder=FileFinder('/usr/lib/python3.8/test'), name='test.ann_module2', ispkg=False)
ModuleInfo(module_finder=FileFinder('/usr/lib/python3.8/test'), name='test.ann_module3', ispkg=False)
ModuleInfo(module_finder=FileFinder('/usr/lib/python3.8/test'), name='test.libregrtest', ispkg=True)
ModuleInfo(module_finder=FileFinder('/usr/lib/python3.8/test/libregrtest'), name='test.libregrtest.cmdline', ispkg=False)
ModuleInfo(module_finder=FileFinder('/usr/lib/python3.8/test/libregrtest'), name='test.libregrtest.main', ispkg=False)
ModuleInfo(module_finder=FileFinder('/usr/lib/python3.8/test/libregrtest'), name='test.libregrtest.pgo', ispkg=False)
ModuleInfo(module_finder=FileFinder('/usr/lib/python3.8/test/libregrtest'), name='test.libregrtest.refleak', ispkg=False)
ModuleInfo(module_finder=FileFinder('/usr/lib/python3.8/test/libregrtest'), name='test.libregrtest.runtest', ispkg=False)
ModuleInfo(module_finder=FileFinder('/usr/lib/python3.8/test/libregrtest'), name='test.libregrtest.runtest_mp', ispkg=False)
ModuleInfo(module_finder=FileFinder('/usr/lib/python3.8/test/libregrtest'), name='test.libregrtest.save_env', ispkg=False)
ModuleInfo(module_finder=FileFinder('/usr/lib/python3.8/test/libregrtest'), name='test.libregrtest.setup', ispkg=False)
ModuleInfo(module_finder=FileFinder('/usr/lib/python3.8/test/libregrtest'), name='test.libregrtest.utils', ispkg=False)
ModuleInfo(module_finder=FileFinder('/usr/lib/python3.8/test/libregrtest'), name='test.libregrtest.win_utils', ispkg=False)
ModuleInfo(module_finder=FileFinder('/usr/lib/python3.8/test'), name='test.regrtest', ispkg=False)
ModuleInfo(module_finder=FileFinder('/usr/lib/python3.8/test'), name='test.support', ispkg=True)
ModuleInfo(module_finder=FileFinder('/usr/lib/python3.8/test/support'), name='test.support.script_helper', ispkg=False)
ModuleInfo(module_finder=FileFinder('/usr/lib/python3.8/test/support'), name='test.support.testresult', ispkg=False)
ModuleInfo(module_finder=FileFinder('/usr/lib/python3.8/test'), name='test.test_support', ispkg=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ah, It need proper prefix.

```
>>> for i in pkgutil.walk_packages(path=['./example',], prefix='example.'):
    print(i)

    
ModuleInfo(module_finder=FileFinder('./example'), name='example.A', ispkg=True)
ModuleInfo(module_finder=FileFinder('/tmp/example/A'), name='example.A.x', ispkg=False)
ModuleInfo(module_finder=FileFinder('./example'), name='example.a', ispkg=False)
ModuleInfo(module_finder=FileFinder('./example'), name='example.b', ispkg=False)
ModuleInfo(module_finder=FileFinder('./example'), name='example.test', ispkg=True)
ModuleInfo(module_finder=FileFinder('/tmp/example/test'), name='example.test.test', ispkg=False)
ModuleInfo(module_finder=FileFinder('/tmp/example/test'), name='example.test.test1', ispkg=False)
```